# Array contains a complete subarray

Tags: arrays, swift

In Swift how can I check whether an array contains a given subarray in its entirety? E.g., is there a `contains` function that works like this:

```
let mainArray = ["hello", "world", "it's", "a", "beautiful", "day"]
contains(mainArray, ["world", "it's"])   // would return true
contains(mainArray, ["world", "it"])   // would return false
contains(mainArray, ["world", "a"])   // would return false - not adjacent in mainArray
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with higher-level functions, like this:

```
func indexOf(data:[String], _ part:[String]) -> Int? {
    // This is to prevent construction of a range from zero to negative
    if part.count > data.count {
        return nil
    }

    // The index of the match could not exceed data.count-part.count
    return (0...data.count-part.count).indexOf {ind in
        // Construct a sub-array from current index,
        // and compare its content to what we are looking for.
        [String](data[ind..<ind+part.count]) == part
    }
}
```

This function returns the index of the first match, if any, or `nil` otherwise.

You can use it as follows:

```
let mainArray = ["hello", "world", "it's", "a", "beautiful", "day"]
if let index = indexOf(mainArray, ["world", "it's"]) {
    print("Found match at \(index)")
} else {
    print("No match")
}
```

**Editing in as an extension to a generic array...**

This can now be used for any homogeneous array of `Equatable` types.

```
extension Array where Element : Equatable {
    func indexOfContiguous(subArray:[Element]) -> Int? {

        // This is to prevent construction of a range from zero to negative
        if subArray.count > self.count {
            return nil
        }

        // The index of the match could not exceed data.count-part.count
        return (0...self.count-subArray.count).indexOf { ind in
            // Construct a sub-array from current index,
            // and compare its content to what we are looking for.
            [Element](self[ind..<ind+subArray.count]) == subArray
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this would work but is possibly too clever for people to understand. (It certainly is for me). Could you possibly add some comments to this to explain what it is doing?

Comment: @Fogmeister Sure! This is much less scary than it looks, though - basically, the "reduce" replaces a "for" loop on the initial index, while `[String](data[ind..<ind+part.count]) == part` replace the loop on the individual values starting at the initial index.

Comment: OK, so it basically does... start at 0. Check the subarray at 0 is equal to the `part` parameter. If it is return 0 all the way through. If it isn't go to 1 and check the subarray at 1 is equal to part parameter and so on?

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes, that's what it does, but it folds the loop into `reduce`, and uses `??` to avoid further checks after the first match is found.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I didn't realise reduce did that. Thanks. I hope you don't mind my edit. Just used your function to make it extend Array of any Equatable type.

Comment: @Fogmeister Thank you very much for the edits! It makes perfect sense to make this more generic.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight How would you optimise this so that the reduce "breaks out" when the first instance of the subArray is found?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Hope you don't mind, I have updated your answer to use `indexOf` rather than `reduce`, allowing the function to short-circuit when it finds a match. Didn't feel like it warranted a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, such a function does not exist. But you can add the functionality with following extension:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    func contains(subarray: [Element]) -> Bool {
        guard subarray.count <= count else { return false }
    
        for idx in 0 ... count - subarray.count {
            let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: idx)
            let end = index(start, offsetBy: subarray.count)
            if Array(self[start ..< end]) == subarray { return true }
        }        
        return false
    }
}
```

Once the extension is added to your project, you can just call:

```
mainArray.contains(["world", "it's"]) // true
mainArray.contains(["world", "it"])   // false
mainArray.contains(["it's", "world"]) // false

let array2 = ["hello", "hello", "world"]
array2.contains(["hello", "world"]) // true
[1, 1, 1, 2].contains(subarray: [1, 1, 2]) // true
```

Comment: Even with the edit, the code will fail for the array `[1, 1, 1, 2]`, `[1, 1, 2]`. This just does not properly restart searching.

Comment: hi @andras, thanks for letting me know. My last edit should fix all remaining issues.

Answer (score 0):

simpleBob's first attempt seems to work with a minimal modification:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    func contains(subarray: [Element]) -> Index? {
        var found = 0
        var startIndex:Index = 0
        for (index, element) in self.enumerate() where found < subarray.count {
            if element != subarray[found] {
                found = 0
            }
            if element == subarray[found]  {
                if found == 0 { startIndex = index }
                found += 1
            }
        }

        return found == subarray.count ? startIndex : nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This idea can be extended to all sequences of equatables.

```swift
public extension Sequence where Element: Equatable {
  /// The iterators of all subsequences, incrementally dropping early elements.
  /// - Note: Begins with the iterator for the full sequence (dropping zero).
  var dropIterators: AnySequence<AnyIterator<Element>> {
    .init(
      sequence(state: makeIterator()) {
        let iterator = $0
        return $0.next().map { _ in .init(iterator) }
      }
    )
  }

  /// - Note: `false` if `elements` is empty.
  func contains<Elements: Sequence>(inOrder elements: Elements) -> Bool
  where Elements.Element == Element {
    elements.isEmpty
      ? false
      : dropIterators.contains {
        AnySequence(zip: ($0, elements))
          .first(where: !=)?.1 == nil
      }
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension Sequence {
  /// The first element of the sequence.
  /// - Note: `nil` if the sequence is empty.
  var first: Element? {
    var iterator = makeIterator()
    return iterator.next()
  }

  /// Whether the sequence iterates exactly zero elements.
  var isEmpty: Bool { first == nil }
}
```

```swift
public extension AnySequence {
  /// Like `zip`, but with `nil` elements for the shorter sequence after it is exhausted.
  init<Sequence0: Sequence, Sequence1: Sequence>(
    zip zipped: (Sequence0, Sequence1)
  ) where Element == (Sequence0.Element?, Sequence1.Element?) {
    self.init(
      sequence(
        state: (zipped.0.makeIterator(), zipped.1.makeIterator())
      ) { iterators in
        Optional(
          (iterators.0.next(), iterators.1.next())
        )
        .filter { $0 != nil || $1 != nil }
      }
    )
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension Optional {
  /// Transform `.some` into `.none`, if a condition fails.
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - isSome: The condition that will result in `nil`, when evaluated to `false`.
  func filter(_ isSome: (Wrapped) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Self {
    try flatMap { try isSome($0) ? $0 : nil }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd add a variation I'm using, which returns the start index of the subarray (or nil). Having the index can be handy, and this better fits the convention used in recent Swift versions (i.e., `firstIndex(of:)` instead of `contains()`).
As a personal tweak, in cases where subarray.count > array.count it will return 0 if the two start with the same elements (nil otherwise). If you don't want this (kinda weird) behaviour you can just return nil from the `guard` block.

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    func firstIndex(ofSubarray subarray: [Element]) -> Int? {
        guard subarray.count <= count else {
            return self == Array(subarray[0 ..< self.count]) ? 0 : nil
        }
        
        for idx in 0 ... count - subarray.count {
            let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: idx)
            let end = index(start, offsetBy: subarray.count)
            if Array(self[start ..< end]) == subarray { return idx }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Arrays do not have the inbuilt capabilities that you are looking for, however you can use sets which are designed to handle such scenarios..

```
let mainSet:Set = ["hello", "world", "it's", "a", "beautiful", "day"]
let list2:Set = ["world", "it's"]
let list3:Set = ["world","a"]
list2.isSubsetOf(mainSet)
```

Comment: Your approach would incorrectly evaluate `["world", "a"]` as a "subarray".

Comment: Yes,off course, to meet that condition probably we may need to use  custom predicate...

Comment: @chitnisprasanna What do you mean by custom predicate? Are you saying "OK my solution doesn't work, I would have to program this"? How would you solve this?

Comment: Solution is still working in Swift 5. 
Don't know, why it was downvoted, but it's good alternative way